# Custom UIButton with setImage not clickable

Tags: swift, uibutton

i have a custom uibutton and in the custom uibutton i am passing a viewModel with an image name and it just calls setImage.The addTarget function is not working.What am i missing here i tried to disable the user interaction on the view because i am setting an imageview on top of it.

CustomButton.swift

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        clipsToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = 9
        layer.borderWidth = 0
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func configure(with viewModel: CustomButtonViewModel ){
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        setImage(UIImage(named: viewModel.image), for: .normal)

        self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
struct CustomButtonViewModel {
    let image : String

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        //Spinner
        // intiate uibuttons
       
    
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bg.png"))
            imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            view = imageView
        
            let dogsButton = CustomButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 140, height: 130))
            let catsButton = CustomButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 100, width: 140, height: 130))
            dogsButton.configure(with: CustomButtonViewModel(image: "dogs.png"))
            catsButton.configure(with: CustomButtonViewModel(image: "cats.png"))
            
            
            dogsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dogsButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            catsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(catsButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(dogsButton)
            view.addSubview(catsButton)
            
        }
        @objc func dogsButtonClicked(sender : UIButton){
            print("dogs button clicked")
    //        let vc = CollectionViewController()
    //        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    //        navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    //        present(navVC, animated: true)
            
        }
        @objc func catsButtonClicked(){
            let vc = CollectionViewController()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: could you please share your CustomButton implementation with the configure method

Comment: i just added the customButton implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning your `UIImageView` to the `UIViewController`s base view and setting it's `isUserInteractionEnabled` property to `false` which will disable the user interaction for all of its subviews, including your buttons. You just have to set this property to true and the touch events will work:

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```